# Getting Nullpointerexception in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am working on App where i am attaching 5 fragments on an activity. Everything is working great but when i put my app in background from any fragment and after some time when my app resumes it crashes. I get reference of my Activty as null. here is my code

This is code in Activty from where i am attaching fragment

```
   FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
   searchFragment = SearchFragment.newInstance(MainBaseActivity.this);
   fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
   fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.frameLayoutMain, searchFragment, "SearchFragment");
   fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

And this is my Fragment class

```
   public static SearchFragment newInstance(MainBaseActivity mainBaseActivity) {

    fragment = new SearchFragment();
    fragment.mainBaseActivity = mainBaseActivity;
    fragment.inflater = (LayoutInflater) mainBaseActivity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    fragment.myApplication = ((MyApplication) mainBaseActivity.getApplicationContext());
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.search_fragment, container, false);

    preferences = mainBaseActivity.getSharedPreferences(Constant.CHAI_APP, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);  // here i get null pointer
    editor = preferences.edit();

    return view;
}
```

Comment: You know. I really like stacktraces provided with questions. So please post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fragments can be killed and recreated by the system at various times. You cannot trust the kind of initialization you do in your `newInstance()` - when the fragment is recreated, the fields won't be initialized.

Remove these initializations:

```
fragment.mainBaseActivity = mainBaseActivity;
fragment.inflater = (LayoutInflater) mainBaseActivity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
fragment.myApplication = ((MyApplication) mainBaseActivity.getApplicationContext());
```

and use `getActivity()` in your fragment when you need to access your hosting activity or the `Application`.

For inflater, one is already passed in as an argument to `onCreateView()`. No need to fetch it yourself.

(To pass params to a fragment that persist over fragment recreation, use `setArguments()`.)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion i ll do as u suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Fragment has the `getActivity()` method to retrieve the activity to which it is attached. Use it in place of `mainBaseActivity`

Comment: I used that but got it as null also

Comment: I don't see it used anywhere

Comment: I meant i used getActivity() at the place of mainbaseactivity but got nullpointer in that case also

Comment: where did you used it? Inside onCreateView or inside newInstance ?

Comment: inside onCreateView()